# How do I get html things to repeat/load outside initial view?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I am making a small web based tool, but running into a problem, both background and hr tags break when the page is larger in width then the initial viewable area. In other words, once I scroll sideways!
**EDIT:** This needs to work for chrome. (Or possibly firefox if not possible in chrome)
Also, thanks to Celts response I can possibly solve the hr issue, background is still not repeating as it should!
However in my real app I don't know the width of the page, as its content and layout are dynamic. (This I could work around with javascript if needed)

Html code for replicating the problem:
And apparently I cant post pictures here yet. So links to the 2 pictures:
Initial view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTwRC.jpg
Scrolled View: https://i.stack.imgur.com/veGY2.jpg

```css
body {
            background: repeating-linear-gradient(
                    90deg,
                    rgba(96, 109, 188, 0.31),
                    rgba(96, 109, 188, 0.30) 100px,
                    rgba(70, 82, 152, 0.31) 100px,
                    rgba(70, 82, 152, 0.31) 200px
            )
        }
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; margin-top: 60px">
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; width: 4000px">
        Text goes here
    </div>
```

Comment: I can't replicate your problem, just checked in IE and all looks fine?

Comment: Sorry, should have added I need this to work in Chrome, (or Maybe firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are setting the div's width to 100% this means it will only ever be as big as the initial screen size that your page loads on. The `hr` tag inside the 100% width div it is getting cut off for this reason. To prevent this from happening set your 100% width div to the same size as the one below it.

This code works fine in chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        body {
            background: repeating-linear-gradient(
                    90deg,
                    rgba(96, 109, 188, 0.31),
                    rgba(96, 109, 188, 0.30) 350px,
                    rgba(70, 82, 152, 0.31) 350px,
                    rgba(70, 82, 152, 0.31) 700px
            )
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 4000px; margin-top: 60px">
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; width: 4000px">
        Text goes here
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You should really build your styles into a separate style sheet. It is good practice and will make future maintenance of the web page much easier.

**UPDATE:**

To solve your repeating background problem you can change your background style to use percentages instead of pixels:

```
<style>
    body {
        background: repeating-linear-gradient(
                90deg,
                rgba(96, 109, 188, 0.31),
                rgba(96, 109, 188, 0.30) 10%,
                rgba(70, 82, 152, 0.31) 10%,
                rgba(70, 82, 152, 0.31) 20%
        )
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it does solve 1 of the 2 problems, however it will only work as a hard value, not for dynamic content. (Edited initial post for more obvious problem when viewing the html result here)

Comment: Yeah you need to use percentages for responsive design. What is the second problem you need to solve? Your question is not very clear..

Comment: The second problem is the background gradient not repeating properly, it "resets" where the inital page ends. (Easily visible in the images I put links to)

Comment: Sorry I just seen your update there. What version of chrome are you using? The background repeats fine for me with the above code..

Comment: Version 40.0.2214.94 m (64-bit)
From what I can tell its the latest, however the background repeat problem can be sublte/not there if the exact width of your browser window (when reloading page I think) is a multiple of the repeat distance. (For me here on stackoverflow with the "run snippet" it simply makes one background stripe wider)

Comment: I seen the problem in your pictures there and have updated my answer with a solution for you.

Comment: Sadly I cant move this to chat, and while your solution works for 20% dividers, (as they are a perfect multiple of page width), they don't solve my problem, or the problem in general.
1: Try 15, 15, 30% bug is there
2: I need the background to be x pixel stripes sadly

(Wish I had a more efficient way of communicating)

Comment: Have a look at this article, looks like the `repeating-linear-gradient` causes a lot of problems. http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2012/05/30/repeating-linear-madness/